# Real Analysis - bounded above (suprema)

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is attached as  a picture.

[image: problem]

Comment: I do not not how to begin answering this question and need some help though i know the definition for the suprema (LUB).

Comment: (1) follows directly from the supremum definition.    (2) is false

Comment: For (1), you could have shown some work. For example, I am sure you can show that $\alpha\cdot S$ is bounded above.

Comment: Can anyone help in editing the question by removing the picture based question.

Comment: @Shu Xiao Li. Would you please check my answer for verification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the definition, $\forall s\in S,s\leq\sup S,$ thus, $a\cdot s\leq a\cdot\sup S$. You should do the other part on your own, which is $\forall t<a\cdot\sup S$, $t$ is not an upper bound of $a\cdot S$.

Part 2) can be easily rejected by constructing a counterexample. Think about it!

Comment: Thanks for help, i will try on my own and might need some verification on my final answer.

Comment: could geometry be used to explain the answer given above.

Comment: @Ittay Weiss.I have written another answer and need some verification on in too.

Answer (score 1):

a).
Suppose that α > 0. The number sup(α.S ) is the unique real number with the properties

(i) sup(α.S ) is an upper bound for α .S and

(ii) if y is any upper bound for α.S, then sup(α.S ) ≤ y

Therefore, because sup(α .S) is the only number for which properties (i) and (ii) are true, to show sup(α.S) = α sup S it is sufficient to show that:

(i) α.sup S is an upper bound for α.S and

(ii) if y is any upper bound for α.S, then α sup S ≤ y.

To show that α.sup S is an upper bound for α.S, suppose that x is in α.S. Then there is an s in S so that x = α s. Then s ≤ sup S since sup S is an upper bound for S and so x = α. s ≤ α sup S. Since x was arbitrary, α sup S is an upper bound for α S.

To show (ii), suppose that y is an upper bound for α S. Then α s ≤ y for every s in S, so s≤ y/α for every s in S. Therefore, y/α is an upper bound for S and so sup S≤ y/α. Multiplying by α we see that α sup S ≤ y as desired.

Therefore  sup(α.S ) = α sup (S)

b). False – If α <0 then α.S will not be an upper bound since α.S will give inf (S).

Comment: Could someone verify my answer as correct or incorrect. Is there any improvements needed.

Comment: The solution is pretty good. b) though isn't very convincing. Instead of messing around with $\inf(S)$, just give a very explicit counterexample. Remember: a simple counterexample is always better than a convoluted explanation. Think of a particular set $S$ and a particular value for $\alpha$ and show the equality does not hold.

Comment: Let y be any upper bound for α.S then α sup S ≤ y but since α < 0 it makes the statement α sup S ≤ y incorrect thus  α.S will not be an upper bound since α.S will give inf (S).

Comment: what have you got against picking out a specific set S=blah and a particular value $\alpha=$blah ???