# Real analysis - converging sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[image: Question inserted as picture]

**My answer**
Solution
1).
$Let\; \epsilon = L/2 > 0 \mbox{thus by definition of}\; x_m→L, \mbox{there exists}\; a \;n_o∈ N \;\mbox{such that }∀m>n_o\; \\
|x_m - L|< ε\\
-ε <|x_m - L| < ε\\
x_m – L > -ε = L - L/2 = ½ L >0$

$2).False\\\mbox {Counter Example Let} x_1=-1,x_2=2, x_3=2……………………..x_n=2$

Comment: Any suggestions for improvement will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You've asked several questions already on SE. It is time you learn to typeset your questions properly using the latex commands. It will greatly improve your ability to use this site more often and more easily.

Comment: I have used latex to type my answers only but am still novice to latex

Comment: @Ittay Weiss. Do you mind checking my solution on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330712/real-analysis-bounded-above-suprema/360065#360065

Comment: I just did. Check out the comment I left on your answer there.

Comment: Your (b) get a correct answer with a wrong example...please read the question more times

Comment: This is a duplcate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/357812)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just consult the definition of limit

a.for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $n_0 \in N$ s.t. for all $n>n_0$ holds that

$$丨x_m-L丨<\epsilon \Rightarrow x_m>L-\epsilon $$

just let $\epsilon = L/2$ or $L/3$ and you can get it

b. consider the sequence $x_n=1/n$ and it's not ture

Comment: Instead of entering an answer to a duplicate question, especially a duplicate answer, consider flagging the question as a duplicate instead.

Comment: @robjohn is it disobey the rule?...i don't know ,but the question is actually the same question...

Comment: Duplicate questions will get closed and sometimes merged. Since you've answered both questions with duplicate answers, I assume you'd noticed that the questions were the same. Posting duplicate answers does not help the site and it creates more work for those who clean up the duplicate questions. There are several things you can do, depending on your reputation. With 15 rep, you can flag a moderator. With 50 rep, you can leave a comment so that a user with at least 3000 rep can vote to close. With 3000 rep, you can vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: @robjohn Thank you for you help,I would.

Answer (score 0):

For your proof of 1) (which is basically correct) try to add some more explanations of what you are doing. For instance, add the word 'thus' between the final three lines. As for 2), the answer is indeed false but your example shows nothing. The example you give is of a sequence of positive elements, except for the first element, and positive limit. Try looking for a sequence of positive elements and limit equal to $0$.

Comment: Why limit equal to zero when L>0

Comment: because you claim (correctly) that the statement is false.